# How to write a Java 3D element on a web page *without* the client installing plug-ins like Java3D

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d

I'm trying to write a 3D demo for a client which will simply display a 3D object on a web page and let them manipulate it with the mouse.

At first I thought I could do this fairly easily with the Java 3D API but it seems that to do so, you have to install it first. It's one thing to get the client to accept that the end-user will have to install a common plugin (Java) but I don't think they'll go for the Java3D API too.

I think I need to use webstart but what confuses me is how can I do 3d in Java without needing the client to install Java 3D?

Bit new to this, sorry if it's complete rubbish.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, the client shouldn't need to download the api - you only have to install it to compile your code, once you build your applet it should be ready to go.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too but then why is it that other demos for Java3D will only run if you have it installed? For example: http://www.fungames.org/reversi.html - on the page: 'If you have any trouble running the applet, read our instructions for installing java 3D.' ...or is it that they've just failed to include the right libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy the Java 3D applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) in a Plug-In 2 architecture (1.6.0_10+) JRE.  JWS makes it simple to install natives, and in fact there is a Java 3D extension JNLP ready to hook into.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought webstart was the answer just didn't know about the plug-in 2 bit. Cheers!

Comment: Clarifying in case I was not clear.  JWS could launch applets since 1.2 (free floating on the desk-top), but the 'Plug-In 2' allows JWS deployed applets to remain embedded in a web page.